# How to return the data from the function but the value that I'm getting is not changed in flutter, how can I change the variable?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

What I'm trying to do is to return the assigned variable and use it as a Text in my Flutter app. I declared the variable as "Results" and after all the changes in the setState() the variable isn't what I want, however when I try to print the variable in the setState() I get the changed variable. How can I change this?

Here is my code and function:

```
var _displayText = 'Results';
    final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    _activateListeners() {
    _database.child('Friday').onValue.listen((event) {
        final description = event.snapshot.value;
        // print(description);
        setState(() {
          final _displayText = '$description';
          Text(_displayText);
        });
      });
      return _displayText;
    }
_activateListeners();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem I needed to return a different variable just like this:

```
String f = "sdjfhg";
    final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    _activateListeners() {
    final _displayText = 'Results';
    _database.child('Friday').onValue.listen((event) {
        final description = event.snapshot.value;
        // print(description);
        setState(() {
          final _displayText = '$description';
          f = _displayText;
          print(f);

          Text(_displayText);
        });
      });
      return f;
    }
```